# dyld: warning being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path

Tags: macos, tensorflow, cpu

I have install tensorflow through GitHub. I think it is the latest version for Mac on cpu.

But whenever I try to import tensorflow, these warnings appear.

dyld: warning, LC_RPATH $ORIGIN/../../_solib_darwin_x86_64/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_C_Upywrap_Utensorflow_Uinternal.so___Utensorflow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path

Although, it seems not affect my simple program. But I'm worrying about it.

Comment: It's probably system integrity protection, there's a way to turn it off, it's recommended for macos tensorflow install

Comment: I know how to close the SIP. But I'm afraid it will cause the system to be unsafe.

Comment: I'm running TensorFlow 1.4.1 on OSX. I'm not concerned about the warning - just annoyed by it. This didn't happen with version 1.2. Any suggestions on how to fix this?